# Ajax return 500 error after upgrading to PHP 7.1

Tags: php, ajax

I'm developing a Wordpress site. Currently testing locally (but same error is also on live site).

It is a common form with Ajax and PHP.
I have enabled error reporting in PHP:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

All errors were fixed, but there is still 500 error that Ajax is catching.

I have checked log on my WAMP server. There are no errors logged any more.

If necessary I can post all my code.

What can be causing this issue?

Comment: "but there is still 500 error that Ajax is catching" — So look at the Network tab in the browser and find out what the error message is.

Comment: I did: admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: That's just the summary. Click on it. Look at the actual response.